# Removing fragments upto 'N' level in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

**What I have done**

***All the fragments are Added one above the other and added to back stack also***

MainActivity - ---->`Fragment_1` --> `Fragment_2` --> `Fragment_3` --> `Fragment_4`--> `Fragment_5` ------ This can go till `N-Numbers` of fragments

**What I am trying to do**:

Asume I am at `Fragment_5`, Then I press a button, I should be able to traverse back to `Fragment_2` by removing fragments all the way upto that level

How to achieve this;

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method:
fragmentManager.popBackStack("The Tag of the fragment", 0);

The description of the method:

> ```
> /**
>  * Pop the last fragment transition from the manager's fragment
>  * back stack.  If there is nothing to pop, false is returned.
>  * This function is asynchronous -- it enqueues the
>  * request to pop, but the action will not be performed until the application
>  * returns to its event loop.
>  *
>  * @param name If non-null, this is the name of a previous back state
>  * to look for; if found, all states up to that state will be popped.  The
>  * {@link #POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE} flag can be used to control whether
>  * the named state itself is popped. If null, only the top state is popped.
>  * @param flags Either 0 or {@link #POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE}.
>  */
> ```